# How do I access a single attribute inside and array within my database - working with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, while-loop

I am attempting to get the 'title' from within an array called 'itemType'. 'itemType' is an attribute inside my model 'Item'.

*ie: **Item { attributes: { name, id, itemType: { title, icon } }***

I have been able to get what I want, but only for a single item. I can not in any way loop through the items to access the whole database at once and get the title for each individual item. Ruby yells at me with :

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

So far I have::

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% len = Item.all.length %>
<% while i < len do %>
    <% items = Item.include_object(:itemType)[i] %>
    <div class="iso_holder">
       <%= item.attributes['itemType']['title']%>
    </div>
    <% i += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

**UPDATE:**

Item Model:

```
class Item < ParseResource::Base
  fields :objectId, :itemType, :user, :createdAt, :updatedAt, :ACL
  validates_presence_of :user

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: What call to `[]` is Ruby unhappy with? The call on line #4 or #6? Also, what's `include_object`?

Comment: Can you post your item.rb code? You're description of the Item model isn't clear.

Comment: It's mad about the second []. The first one prints out just fine when looping through all the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems not to use the power or ruby

This should help.

```
<% Item.all.each do |item| %>
    <div class="iso_holder">
       <%= item.itemType.title unless item.itemType.nil? %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My Probable guess is you are getting `itemType` as `nil` somewhere in some record

also have a short look at [loops in ruby](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/loops.htm)

I personally feel its not worth using ruby if you are writing the same way you code in other langs :)

Comment: This also throws a similar error message unfortunately. Ruby still doesn't like those brackets for some reason.   [undefined method `[]' for #<ItemType:0x30a58d0>]

Comment: It takes an extremely long time to actually load, but it works :) Thank you!

Comment: maybe due to some reasons its taking time, but this is the proper way to use loops with objects there are others ways too check them out

Comment: p.s. The only reason that while loop was being used at all is because I had tried writing this specific part of the code every way I could think of and nothing worked. I'm not really sure how this is much different than the very first way I wrote it. I'm new to Ruby though - little things do make quite the difference.

Comment: @PriteshJ - I have to agree. Leigha, you should work through some Ruby and Ruby on Rails tutorials. You'll find that you can accomplish a great deal with very little code once you get the swing of it.

Comment: @Leigha. i recommend giving some time to learn ruby/rails basics instead of scratching head on such problems.there is ample docs available now on both rails and ruby. and if you get stuck you are always welcome here :)